# Truffle console - How can I get and print the value returned by a contract function?

Tags: truffle

This is an absolute newbie question. Given this simple Hello World contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Greeter {

    function Greeter() {}

    function sayHello() returns(string) {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I deploy it and try to get the value from the `sayHello()` function:

```
$ truffle compile
$ truffle deploy
$ Greeter.deployed().then(function(instance){ return instance.sayHello()}).then(function(result){console.log(result);});
```

I was expecting to see "hello" in the output of the above statement but this is what I actually get:

```
{ tx: '0xa4333e052b00fdf00d9ad944862b592d091cfb4ff68d610e297cb52cfbf5ebfd',
  receipt: 
   { transactionHash: '0xa4333e052b00fdf00d9ad944862b592d091cfb4ff68d610e297cb52cfbf5ebfd',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0x40aca77673267ca149fe34a62c95b2869285d7819d21279d59fc0714c702314c',
     blockNumber: 64,
     gasUsed: 21867,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 21867,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [] },
  logs: [] }
undefined
```

That is to say, result is an object of this information instead of the "hello" string. Is there a way I can get the actual result of the function?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you get is the result of the transaction.
You can only get the return value of `constant` function. Do it like that :

```
function sayHello() constant returns(string) {
    return "hello";
}
```

An other solution is to use `.call()`

```
function saveData(uint _data) returns(bool) {
    data = _data;
    return true;
}
```

If you use `.call()`, the data will not be saved but you will get the return value. The typical case is to call the function with `.call()` the first time to see if the execution went good, and then call again the function without the `.call()`.

Comment: Is there any way to get result from non-constant functions?

Comment: yes, you need to add `.call()` when calling your function. Note that the modification will not be save in the blockchain. Look at the Nsevens's answer.

Comment: I am asking about NON-constant functions. Looks like this is Web3 restriction.

Comment: For completeness: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33154/function-call-behaves-differently-to-function-in-truffle-test

Only now realized `.call()` does not save the thing! Wasted so much time...

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the same result with

```
Greeter.deployed().then(function(instance) {return instance.sayHello.call()})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the return value of a non constant/view/pure function you may use return the value and use 'then'.

```
Greeter.deployed().then(function(instance) { return instance.sayHello() }).then(function (value) {
   // Now value contains the return value os the sayHello() function
   console.log(value);
})
```

Comment: That's basically the same as what they have in their example.

Comment: Yes, I think that doesn't solve the problem, because you just get a tx result object back, not the "return value" as specified in the contract