# function.call() behaves differently to function() in truffle test

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-invocation, testing

I'm using Truffle 4.0.1 and Node 9.2.1

In my solidity smart contract I have a function

```
function finalize() public onlyOwner {
    require(!isFinalized);

    finalization(); // does some stuff
    Finalized();

    isFinalized = true;
}
```

In my test I have the following

```
await contract.finalize.call()
const isFinalized = await contract.isFinalized.call()
console.log('isFinalized', isFinalized)
```

which outputs

```
isFinalized false
```

If I change my code to read

```
const tx = await contract.finalize()
const isFinalized = await contract.isFinalized.call()
console.log('isFinalized', isFinalized)
```

then it outputs

```
isFinalized true
```

Why is there a difference?

Comment: not really a duplicate as my context is more about testing, although that question does explain what's going on, so thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first example, when you execute await contract.finalize.call() using call() executes the function without modifying the state, which makes the changes to state variables being made inside the function call "not getting saved".

You should use .call() to execute constant/view/pure functions that don't modify state variables. With truffle you can even forgo the .call().

If the Solidity function is marked as view/constant/pure, truffle will know you are trying just to read a value and not modifying anything.

Comment: I'm using `call` because `solcov` wants me to.  Something to do with how it instruments solidity code.

Comment: Small internet. Just wasted a lot of time on that, woke up, fresh mind, now I understand the issue :) https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16796/truffle-console-how-can-i-get-and-print-the-value-returned-by-a-contract-funct