# I want a to write a function to get user data by giving the id of the user

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract ChainList  {

  struct  data  {
    uint   ownernumber;
    uint   id;
  }

  uint value;
  mapping (uint256 => data) public  datamatching;

  function storedata (uint _ownernumber, uint _id) public {
    var  persondata  = datamatching[value];
    persondata .ownernumber = _ownernumber;
    persondata. id  =  _id;
  }

  function getData(uint256 userId) returns (uint, uint){
    return (datamatching[userId].ownernumber, datamatching[userId].id);
  }
}
```

// I have written the function but I tought that when I call the get function it will return all the child varables but it  is not working

```
truffle(development)> app.storedata(123344,1)
{ tx: '0x1fad231de1e19b004c8004871036a7cf47be06ab4123614130f1b1371371433b',
  receipt: 
   { transactionHash: '0x1fad231de1e19b004c8004871036a7cf47be06ab4123614130f1b1371371433b',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0xbff254564dc0d2e8affc80ca5994a66be5c06377f98ff425783c9b02fd36c75c',
     blockNumber: 20,
     gasUsed: 62379,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 62379,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [],
     status: 1 },
  logs: [] }
truffle(development)> app.getData(123344)
{ tx: '0x327089e695085696d00c5656db322bce490bc17bf0edaa19f17dad38cdf74377',
  receipt: 
   { transactionHash: '0x327089e695085696d00c5656db322bce490bc17bf0edaa19f17dad38cdf74377',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0x85ccd6ccc26417365681525442b0349ce29a1a46b9de4184ca1f1e3ec4b66fd4',
     blockNumber: 21,
     gasUsed: 22454,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 22454,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [],
     status: 1 },
  logs: [] }
truffle(development)> 
undefined
truffle(development)> 
undefined
truffle(development)> app.storedata(123344,3)
{ tx: '0xafb132e70bfb82e1d41227bf41d787faaf6ee9d99c63fa3145752e2178b5a4e6',
  receipt: 
   { transactionHash: '0xafb132e70bfb82e1d41227bf41d787faaf6ee9d99c63fa3145752e2178b5a4e6',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0x61dacd6a0a2d48627b3becc2a815ec7b72a7fe175497ef66964dffdd3bdf2c6f',
     blockNumber: 22,
     gasUsed: 32379,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 32379,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [],
     status: 1 },
  logs: [] }
truffle(development)> app.getData(123344)
{ tx: '0x63c83f31d384494ed8ad6389c43d2a5745a6e229242c5fb6218386b3387d6409',
  receipt: 
   { transactionHash: '0x63c83f31d384494ed8ad6389c43d2a5745a6e229242c5fb6218386b3387d6409',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0x7c3252574ffcd2f65f207b279d1b7501655e2638ddd52397c8fde93a9be4cb00',
     blockNumber: 23,
     gasUsed: 22454,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 22454,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [],
     status: 1 },
  logs: [] }
```

When I call getData with id  123344  it should return the two values  1 and 3 because I used the same id  to store the both varibles but it is showing a different hash.

I want to getdata to show the hash of the two transactions id's  and the values  1 and 2 when user calls it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your contract is in the line:

```
var  persondata  = datamatching[value];
```

This line should be:

```
var  persondata  = datamatching[_id];
```

Note:
I would do: `data storage persondata  = datamatching[_id];`

EDIT

Another issue is that you are using truffle and you want to get the returned value of the function getData. Truffle will only give you teh result of the transaction.

Instead, you can use .call() at the end of your function in truffle to get the value of the variable.

Hope this helps

Comment: HI 
can you plese explain what is data storage

Comment: data Is the name you give to the struct. Storage means that the variable persondata is a pointer  to a variable in the storage of the contract and is of type "data" as defined in the struct. If this solved your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: sorry james 
On paper it seems correct but when compiling i  still not getting  the desired output (so i am trying to use events )  if you don't mind can you check once in your machine 
But Thanks a lot for your support  i want to give upvote but i  can't  due to low score .
Hope you Understand

Comment: what do you mean by not getting the desired output? I tested it on remix, I save the data with storedata and then I am able to retrieve it, please explain what is that you do not get. Also, why are you talking about events?

Comment: I have deployed using truffle and stored in a app varable
 app.storedata(123344,1)
{ tx: '0x6b5188860f04df168e2b36c45dfbdde78f7303c416c0918e3f4fa52cf931ceff',
  receipt: 
   { transactionHash: '0x6b5188860f04df168e2b36c45dfbdde78f7303c416c0918e3f4fa52cf931ceff',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0x0682f6a263654e005c4dd86e92cf905faa5ae061ebdc8e0ad27132e7e411c3da',
     blockNumber: 5,
     gasUsed: 62179,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 62179,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [],
     status: 1 },
  logs: [] }

Comment: See my updated answer. try app.getData(123344).call()

Comment: app.getData(123344).call()
TypeError: app.getData(...).call is not a function

Comment: Sorry I wrote to you how I will do this on python instead of truffle. See this answer (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16796/truffle-console-how-can-i-get-and-print-the-value-returned-by-a-contract-funct) to see how to get the retuened values in truffle. Good luck